# namespace vs naming convention

Tags: c++, namespaces, naming-conventions

Recently I've started a new small project for my own and was reading some literature about naming conventions. Independent of which coding style is preferred, [google coding style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml)
or [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) (in my opinion the system hungarian style (even if somebody think it is not a good style) not apps style) or some other styles I'm not mentioned. I though about using a naming convention or make it by namespaces. Also I've read this [post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

My attention is on inheritance.

google like example:

```cpp
class MyClassInterface {
  int some_stuff() = 0;
};

class MyClassA : MyClassInterface {
  int some_stuff() { return 1; }
};

class MyClassB : MyClassInterface {
  int some_stuff() { return 2; }
};
```

Now, my idea was to using namespaces:

```
namespace my {

namespace interface {
class Class {
  int some_stuff() = 0;
};
} // namespace interface

namespace a {
class Class : interface::Class {
  int some_stuff() { return 1; }
};
} // namespace a

namespace b {
class Class : interface::Class {
  int some_stuff() { return 2; }
};
} // namespace b

} // namespace my
```

The advantage of this kind of naming can be seen in this example:

```
using namepsace my;

void foo(interface::Class lala) {
  // do something;
}

// ...
int main() {
  using namespace a;

  Class bar;
  foo(bar);

  b::Class bar2;
  foo(bar2);
}
```

Now I can type a `using namespace` and it will always use the preferred one, but all other child classes are still reachable by there namespaces.

So my question is, is this a good idea, or are there some disadvantages which I don't see?

### edit:

I also could use

```
namespace my {

namespace interface {
class Class {
  int some_stuff() = 0;
};
} // namespace interface

class ClassA : interface::Class {
  int some_stuff() { return 1; }
};

class ClassB : interface::Class {
  int some_stuff() { return 2; }
};

} // namespace my
```

To not nest to much namespaces.

### Addendum

I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right place to put the question in, but on programmers there is not even a tag naming-convention (but naming-standards). And there is not really a lot of discussion on namespaces and naming-conventions. If it's wrong i could move my question.

Comment: You will find more opinions on how to do these things than there are possibilities to do these things.

Comment: Be careful. One namespace is definitely a good idea. Once you add nested namespaces you may need to know about how ADL works.

Comment: @Simple the main purpose is to set the interface in a namespace. i also could do `class ClassA : public interface::Class {};` and `class ClassB : public interface::Class {};`. if this would be *nicer*.

Comment: @itwasntpete you shouldn't put every little thing into its own namespace. As an example, the `std` namespace has very little nested namespaces.

Comment: don't use Google Style guide as a guide to learn good C++ practices. Is a guide to help with the manteniance of old C++ google code.

Comment: I think a good rule is: Use namespaces to identify a library (The cntents of a library). Use nested namespaces in very specific cases (Cases where the content of that nested namespace could be considered a library itself).

Comment: Using the shift key - while typing - has been a concern in coding style and naming conventions. Capital letters, underscore and colon, all need that little extra burden. With capitalization(QT) you get shorter names. While underscore(std/boost) increases readability - due to resultant spacing. Namespacing  brings modularity, less name pollution, sometimes shorter code, in expense of one extra shift pressing while using fully qualified names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a good rule is: Use namespaces to identify a library (The contents of a library). Use nested namespaces in very specific cases (Cases where the contents of that nested namespace could be considered a library itself).

An example of that could be the standard library: It provides its functionality through the `std` namespace, and (for example) provides the chrono library (it could be viewed as a library itself) through the `std::chrono` namespace. Other example could be Boost and its libraries.

Comment: boost is exactly why i'm asking. for example looking on boost::asio, there is a lot of nested namspaces (boost::asio::ip::udp) which offers the advantage of replacing e.g `udp` by `tcp`. also boost alway's use a namespace `detail_` for some *internal* stuff. i thought to use `namespace interface` instead of detail_, because 1st it is used most internal 2nd it is more nice have it in a namespace as though in the name (classInterface). my first advice was, please see my edit. the only problem now i see is the ADL what Simple mentioned in his comment.